What kind of restrictions are there for foreign direct investments in Malaysia?
What kind of restrictions are there for foreign direct investments (FDIs) in Malaysia?

By countries (Is there any country-wise restriction for FDI in Malaysia?)
By industries (What kind of restriction will be there for advertising/ Media/ communication industry?)
Any other restrictions/ incentives need to be considered for the FDI in Malaysia.

